# JAX-WS SSL Handshake Exception

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, glassfish

I am connecting to a secure web service using a jax-ws client.  The web site uses a self signed certificate which I've imported to a custom keystore and created a Socket Factory in line with many articles on this site.

However, I keep getting **sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target** each time I try to connect to the web service. If I set the default SSL Context to the custom context, I can execute as a standalone client, but after deploying to the Glassfish app server, the same error surfaces.

Any ideas will be most welcome.  Below is the code extract that creates the SSL Context.

```
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(Client.class.getResourceAsStream("hfcerts"), "changeit".toCharArray() );
        kmf.init(ks, "changeit".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, new SecureRandom());

        SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, ctx.getSocketFactory());
```

Also, I do not want my settings to affect the general SSL settings on the App server.

Comment: your code looks fine, so I'd suspect something wrong with the keystore. Make sure you have the cert loaded (not the private key). If the certificate chain has multiple CAs you may want to include those as well.